# DynamoDB scan all items that meet condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB script. I scan for item that meet a certain condition. Now it works but for tables with a lot of items it seems that it only prints some of the items that match, not all of them:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')
table = dynamodb.Table(table)

# get items
fe = Attr('message').contains(filter)
get_response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=fe
)

print(get_response)
```

But this prints not all of the items.

Answer (score 3):

The [scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) method without pagination will (according to the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan)),

> A single Scan operation reads up to the maximum number of items set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression

Try using the [scan paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Scan)

```py
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
paginator = dynamodb.get_paginator('scan')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    TableName=table,
    FilterExpression='Message = :filter',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":filter": {
            "S": "some filter"
        }
    }
)

for response in response_iterator:
    print(response)
```

The `FilterExpression` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` will depend on what you're looking for. check the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) for more details

Comment: Thank you, now I try that I get Invalid type for parameter FilterExpression, value: <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Contains object at 0x0000016D69556A00>, type: <class 'boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Contains'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Comment: You cannot use `Attr` objects in the paginators. You need to construct the FilterExpression by hand. This is a very annoying boto3 issue

Comment: updated answer for clarification on FilterExpression

Comment: Thanks, I try to understand it in my use case where I need a contains